# Character Encodings when switching from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, character-encoding

I created a tex-file on Ubuntu. Now I upload the file via FTP on an Apache-Webserver. I am pretty sure, that the server is a unix-based server. After that I download the file from the webserver and I open it with JEdit on Windows-7 and german umlaute (ä, ö, etc.) are looking strange.

I thought: if I change the file-attributes in JEdit to UTF-8 all should be fine, but nevertheless, umlaute are still looking strange.

How can I handle the file-encoding dilemma?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What file upload mode of FTP are you using?

Comment: I think you're using ASCII mode, where the server will try to understand your bytes as ASCII, which won't work well for those German characters like ö. Try switching to binary mode for the transactions.

Comment: I do not know - I guess Filezilla's default behaviour. As 'Transertyp' on Windows-site I can see 'automatic'. Anyway I have no idea what's the configuration on Ubuntu-Filezilla, which actually was responsible for the file upload.

Comment: Great, choosing binary handled this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Transfers -> File Types in FileZilla and set to binary for the extension you're using for your text file.

If you're using the command line clients, try `binary` to switch to binary mode.